# How to update date field in mongo console?

Tags: mongodb

For example I want to update all records to '2012-01-01' (  "time" : ISODate("2011-12-31T13:52:40Z") ).

```
db.test.update( { time : '2012-01-01' }, false, true  )
```

return error:

```
Assert failed : need an object
Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@shell/utils.js:35
("assert failed : need an object")@shell/utils.js:46
(false,"need an object")@shell/utils.js:54
([object Object],false,true)@shell/collection.js:189
@(shell):1

Wed Jan 11 17:52:35 uncaught exception: assert failed : need an object
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need to create a new `ISODate` object like this:

```
db.test.insert({"Time" : new ISODate("2012-01-10") });
```

This is true both for updates and for queries. Note that your query syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
db.test.update({ criteria }, { newObj }, upsert, multi);
```

For example, to update all objects, consider

```
db.test.update( {}, { $set : { "time" : new ISODate("2012-01-11T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Also note that this is very different from

```
db.test.update( {}, { "time" : new ISODate("2012-01-11T03:34:54Z") }, true, false);
```

because the latter will **replace** the object, rather than add a new field to the existing document or updating the existing field. In this example, I changed the last parameter to `false`, because multi updates only work with `$` operators.

Comment: Note that as of this writing the `update` method is deprecated, use `updateOne` or `updateMany` instead. [To see more compatability changes, take a look here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/#std-label-compatibility)

Answer (score 7):

If you need to convert an existing date field (imported from MySQL format 'yyyy-mm-dd' f.e.) to ISODate you can loop through the documents this way:

```
/usr/bin/mongo yourdbname --eval "db.yourcollectionname.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.yourdatefield = new ISODate(doc.yourdatefield);db.yourcollectionname.save(doc)});"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in the old-school way by creating ISO date

```
  db.test.update({_id : 1}, {
      $set : {
         "time" : new ISODate("your current date")
      }
  });
```

But note that with new `Mongo 2.6` you will be able to update date to a current date really easy with [$currentDate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate).

```
db.test.update( { _id: 1 }, {
  $currentDate: {
      time: true,
  },
})
```