# Mongo findAndUpdate for updating multiple documents

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to use mongo findAndUpdate to update multiple documents and keep receiving syntax error:

```
db.forecasts.findAndModify({
   query: {forDate: ISODate("2016-02-25T05:00:00.000+0000")},
   update: {
      { $set: {forDate: ISODate("2016-02-23T05:00:00.000+0000")}}, 
      {multi: true}
     }
   })
```

Alternately I also tried:

```
db.forecasts.update({
   {'forDate': ISODate("2016-02-25T05:00:00.000+0000")},
   {'forDate': ISODate("2016-02-23T05:00:00.000+0000")}, 
   {multi: true}  
   })
```

The error I receive is :
`Error at line 2 position 3: <missing ')`'

Comment: Those are typographical error: the value of `update` key is `{ {...}, {...} }`: such syntax does not exists in JSON. However, as the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#comparisons-with-the-update-method) explains, `findAndModify` cannot modify more than one document.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "findAndModify" that works on multiple documents. There are many reasons why such a thing would not make sense anyway. Either update the documents and then search for them separately in another query, or iterate `.findAndModify()` for every document individually that would match a condition.

Comment: The specific "errors" are based on syntactical errors, and mostly with breaking the rules of how to structure an object. Simply applying in `multi` would be `.update({ forDate: ISODate("2016-02-25T05:00:00.000+0000") },{ "$set": {  forDate: ISODate("2016-02-25T05:00:00.000+0000")  } },{ "multi": true })`. Not that it would do anything, since you are setting to the same value that you are matching, and MongoDB will "smartly" recongnize this.

Answer (score 5):

Use simple update query here, last 2 true's  are for "**upsert**" and "**multi**"

```
db.forecasts.update( {"forDate":ISODate("2016-02-25T03:34:54Z")}, { $set : { "forDate" : new ISODate("2016-03-23T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Comment: It's the other way around! The upsert and multi: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 4):

`findAndModify()` doesn't allow  `{multi: true}`. You can only update one document and it returns the original doc (default) or uou can ask for thr updated doc.

Comment: _Although the query may match multiple documents, 
findAndModify
 will **only select one** document to modify._  – [findAndModify reference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#command-fields) → Command Fields → `query`

Answer (score 0):

The following thread helped resolve the issue:

[How to update date field in mongo console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821206/how-to-update-date-field-in-mongo-console)

```
db.forecasts.update( {}, { $set : { "forDate" : new ISODate("2016-02-23T03:34:54Z") } }, true, true);
```

Comment: This update query will update all the documents, but question is asking to update only the documents with provided date. So @Nishant's answer is recommended.